# Rails' equivalent to Controller's Afterfilter in CakePHP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cakephp

I'm coming from CakePHP to Rails.

In Cake, we had afterFilter that could be defined as a callback after a controller action has been processed.

Do we have any feature like this in Rails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called `after_filter` in rails, as in

```
after_filter :foobar #run foobar after the action
```

Comment: Interesting, however, is it normal that Rails attempt to render the template before calling after_filter ?

Comment: I believe that is the case, as usually, the render call happens inside the action (i.e. before the framework would be able to pass control to any callbacks).